# Not able to share question on Facebook

Tags: bug, status-norepro, facebook, sharing

I am trying to share my question on Facebook via the share button, but  Facebook gives an error like  "You can't post this because it has a blocked link".

Here is the screen shot of the exception generated by FB.

[image: screen shot]

This is the question URL:

[problem with commitEditingStyle -to delete cell in the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857711/problem-with-commiteditingstyle-to-delete-cell-in-the-table)

These are the steps to reproduce:

1. Open above URL of my question
2. Click on "share" and select FB
3. Then click on share button (I am already logged in to FB)
4. Get the error shown in the screen shot

Can anybody help?

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86469/354

Comment: seems to work for me. I was able to actually share/post it both via the share button and via my fb timeline.

Comment: @m0sa actually I submit this url to facebook report team that's why might be resolved from them side.